# How to prevent the actionMode and toolbar to "jump" when toggling between them?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-actionmode

### Background

I have an activity in my app that has a toolbar as the actionBar, and it also has an actionMode, for multi-selection of items.

### The problem

Every time I close the actionMode, there is a "jump" between the two modes, so I can see both the toolbar and the actionMode.

Maybe I'm just doing it wrong, but I remember it worked fine in the past.

Here's how it looks like using the snippet code I've made:

[image]

### What I've tried

This is a snippet of the code I've used. To test it, run the app, wait a moment for the actionMode to appear, and then either press the back button, or press the button on the actionMode. Do note that all classes that I use are of the support library (when available).

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected ActionMode.Callback _actionModeCallback;
    protected ActionMode _actionMode;
    Toolbar _toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        _toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.activity_app_list__toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
        _actionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(final ActionMode mode, final Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(final ActionMode mode) {
                _toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                _actionMode = null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(final ActionMode mode, final Menu menu) {
                _toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(final ActionMode mode, final MenuItem item) {
                mode.finish();
                return true;
            }
        };
        //
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _actionMode = startSupportActionMode(_actionModeCallback);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/activity_app_list__toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:colorControlNormal="?attr/colorControlNormal"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some Text"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->.
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0288D1</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

### The question

Why is this happenning? How can I fix it?

Is this a known bug, perhaps?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? People who downvote should write down the reason for this. Otherwise it doesn't teach anything and isn't informative :(

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the `ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY` flag. In your Activity.onCreate() method, add the following before the call to `super.onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // other stuff...
}
```

Comment: This fixes the issue of the toolbars, but now the content below becomes behind the actionMode. Maybe I should set the layout to be a FrameLayout, and the content below the toolbar have a margin instead of being below it ? Also, is it possible to set what you wrote via themes instead? I've also noticed that when going to actionMode, I see the background of the window for a short time. Should I put there a view with the background of the toolbar?

Comment: I think "windowActionModeOverlay" can do the same if being used in the themes. In fact, I used it in the original app, but I don't remember why I've set it to false instead of setting it to true. Perhaps this is how it used to work till recently.

Comment: Anyway, if you have a suggestion about how to make the transition to the actionMode work nicely, please let me know. For now, you get +1 for the effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

The same as described by @Kevin Coppock can also be achieved by adding `<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>` in your `AppTheme`.

The theme could look like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->.
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF0288D1</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```